# how can use a custom method in controller in asp net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i m trying to learn something in asp net mvc.

i could not handle a problem.

i have a custom class like

```
public class trenMethod
{
    public testDBContex db;
    public List<IsSoSu> ListAll()

    { 
        var Name= from a in db.test1
                   from b in db.test2
                   where a.Name== b.Name
                   select new IsSoSu()
                   {
                       NameLast=a.Name,
                       MidNameLast=a.MidName,
                       SurnameLast=b.Surname
                   };
       return Name.ToList();
    }
```

it s ok with that. but when i want to use this method in controller, the method does not seem.

```
public ActionResult IndexTrEn()
    {
        trenMethod.    <there is nothing in here> ( i expect that trenMethod.ListAll(); but there is nothing except "Equals, ReferenceEquals" ) }
```

where i make mistake?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: There's nothing there because your `ListAll` method isn't static and you're trying to call it as if it were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate the class and use the object:

```
public ActionResult IndexTrEn()
{
        var tm = new trenMethod();
        tm.ListAll();
        ...
}
```